# How to plot mean of multiple columns?

Tags: r

this is probably a very basic question but I'm just starting out using R and hope someone can help.

I've imported some data into R and created an object containing just the data I'm working on first:

[image]

Each of the values is from a scale of 1 to 10.

What I want to produce is a chart showing the mean of each column, something like this (which I did in Excel):

[image]

I'm sure this is possible, but I'm going round in circles figuring it out! Ignoring the vertical line (at maximum value) and standard deviations for now, though ultimately I'd like to have them included. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to copy the data to test and verify solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(4, sample(10, 50, replace=TRUE))), c("2000", "2400", "2800", "3200"))
head(dat)
#   2000 2400 2800 3200
# 1    1    6    5    1
# 2    5    6    9    1
# 3    1    2   10    5
# 4    9    4    8    3
# 5   10    3    7   10
# 6    4    6    6    1

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(name = as.integer(name)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: This produces an error: `Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
  no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: I've seen that error [before](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2514), and (in those cases) it had nothing to do with this code; it was due to `ggplot2`'s mis-handling of resizing of the graphics pane/window. If you are using RStudio, I suggest restart R and RStudio and try again. If you are using Rterm (or emacs/ess or similar) then close the R graphics window (and/or `dev.off()`) and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have encoded a numerical value in the column name, which is not a good idea, because it is a violation of the first normal form. I would thus suggest to transpose the data and encode the first value in the first column.

With your peculiar data structure, you must first extract the number from the colmn names with

```
x <- as.numeric(names(dat))
```

Then you can compute all column means with

```
y <- colMeans(dat)
```

And then you can plot it

```
plot(x, y, type="l")
```